# GlobalEventHandlers.onclick browser compatibility

Tags: javascript

Is there any official information about the **GlobalEventHandlers.onclick** browser compatibility? 
[image]

Comment: What is your question? You as about compatibility and at the same time post an image that shows the compatibilly.

Comment: @Poku there are no compatibility information, do not you see? It is just about **Chrome**. i need to know about **GlobalEventHandlers.onclick** Desctop and Mobile browsers compatibility